# ¿Como cambiar el texto de h3 desde asp.net, lo hago de la manera de la descripción pero no me funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

El codigo es el siguiente tanto el codebehind como el del designer, la idea es cambiar el texto del h3 al cambiar la seleccion del radiobutton, pero no ejecuta el codigo de jquery el texto queda en Agregar Nuevo Producto/Servicio y no cambia a Desasociar Producto/Servicio

```
protected void rdasounoauno_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string script = "cambiatexto();";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "F1", script, true);

}

<div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading" >
                                <h3 class="panel-title" id="panelconteasocia">
                                    Agregar Nuevo Producto/Servicio
                                </h3>
                            </div>
 </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function cambiatexto() {

             $("#panelconteasocia").text = "Desasociar Producto/Servicio";       
}
</script>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar .text por .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
$("#panelconteasocia").text = "Desasociar Producto/Servicio";
```

En jQuery, el texto se cambia de esta forma:

```
$("#panelconteasocia").text("Desasociar Producto/Servicio");
```

Comment: Oye gracias alanfcm útil, problema resuelto, no me daba error la babosada =) por eso no lo hallaba

Comment: lol, babosada, de nada